# Почему код иногда выдаёт разные результаты при одинаковых данных

Tags: python

На сбоящем этапе код должен считывать сумму модулей отрицательных нечётных элементов столбцов матрицы и записывать эту сумму в одномерный массив. Но он почему-то иногда и вовсе выдаёт отрицательные значения. Ошибка появляется только, если он добавляет число в ненулевой элемент массива. То есть добавляет число в этот элемент во второй раз. Но даже так, ошибка встречается не каждый раз.
При этом, даже стоящие рядом *"print (characteristic[j] + -1 * array[i][j])"* и *"characteristic[j] += -1 * array[i][j];                 print (characteristic[j])"* иногда выдают разные ответы.
Чтобы запустить программу, надо ввести размер матрицы. Так как ошибка не появляется при первом добавлении, нужно создать сравнительно большую матрицу, например 13x13.

```
from random import(uniform)
import numpy as np
n = int(input('Введите количество строк матрицы'))
m = int(input('Введите количество столбцов матрицы'))
answer = "z"
array = np.zeros((n,m), dtype="int8")
characteristic = np.zeros((m), dtype="int8") # вот тут ошибка
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        array[i][j] = uniform(-1000, 0)
        if array[i][j] < 0 and array[i][j] % 2 == 1: #ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА
            print("___")
            print (array[i][j])
            print (characteristic[j] + -1 * array[i][j]) #ВЫВОД СУММЫ
            characteristic[j] += -1 * array[i][j] #СУММИРОВАНИЕ
            print (characteristic[j]) #ВЫВОД ПОСЛЕ СУММИРОВАНИЯ (ИНОГДА ВЫДАЁТ ДРУГОЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ. ЧЕМ БОЛЬШЕ МАССИВ, ТЕМ ВЫШЕ ШАНС ВСТРЕТИТЬ ОШИБКУ)
```

Пример вывода, где видно, что ошибка произошла лишь один раз:
Введите количество строк матрицы
5
Введите количество столбцов матрицы
5

---

-119
119
119

---

-81
81
81

---

-3
3
3

---

-65
65
65

---

-33
114
114

---

-89
208
-48

** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit termi

Comment: Исправьте на `dtype="int32"`. "Ошибки" уйдут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `c` получает тип `int64` из-за умножения на `-1`. Значение `b[0]` имеет тип `int8` - оно хранится в массиве этого типа. Разница из-за приведения первого ко второму:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.zeros((1, ), dtype="int8")
b = np.zeros((1, ), dtype="int8")
a[0] = 127
for _ in range(10):
    c = b[0] + -1 * a[0]
    b[0] += -1 * a[0]
    print(type(c), c, type(b[0]), b[0])
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -127 <class 'numpy.int8'> -127
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -254 <class 'numpy.int8'> 2
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -125 <class 'numpy.int8'> -125
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -252 <class 'numpy.int8'> 4
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -123 <class 'numpy.int8'> -123
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -250 <class 'numpy.int8'> 6
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -121 <class 'numpy.int8'> -121
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -248 <class 'numpy.int8'> 8
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -119 <class 'numpy.int8'> -119
> <class 'numpy.int64'> -246 <class 'numpy.int8'> 10
> ```